# Relationship many to many in java

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I have a problem with the relationship many to many. Please see my code and tell me is it good or not

my code in class stagiaire

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy ="stagiaires")
  private Set<Session> sessions;
```

in class session

```
@ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="session_stagiaire")
    private Set<Stagiaire> stagiaires;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look here to learn how to improve your questions (formatting, proofreading, providing code etc.): https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: First use generics. It will be always good. 
private Set<session> sessions

Second initialise always.
private Set<session> sessions = new HashSet<>();

Third see if you can set fetch mode to lazy, it will avoid unnecessary db interactions.

Third use camel case for classes. Session. Stagiaire

Comment: thank you I will try what you write to me